# Firebase Database not being implemented due to session error

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, dialogflow-es, firebaseui

I'm building a chat bot which I have integrated with Dialogflow and Firebase. How can I fix session error issue (shown below) in Firebase logcat? Is it due to an issue in my Android Studio or my connection with Firebase? I am getting an issue in inflating my recycler view too which uses FirebaseRecyclerAdapter to inflate it.

1. Firebase app registration to connect to its server was taking a lot of time, so I skipped the step thinking I would connect it through my google-json file.
2. Since I am using Firebase UI Database v5.0.0 I had to change the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter method according to the recent update given here: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md

Manifest File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.internchatbot">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
        android:appComponentFactory="androidx">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />


                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

app.gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:18.0.0'
    // FirebaseUI for Firebase Realtime Database
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:5.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:19.0.1'
    //implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:2.3.0'
    implementation 'ai.api:sdk:2.0.7@aar'
    //implementation

    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
    implementation "ai.api:libai:1.6.12"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AIListener{  //because I am recording audio too

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    EditText editText;
    RelativeLayout addBtn;
    private DatabaseReference ref;            //declaration of variables
    Boolean flagFab = true;



final   AIConfiguration config = new AIConfiguration("0c01e159babc4349b38eca698bd2f107",
            AIConfiguration.SupportedLanguages.English,
            AIConfiguration.RecognitionEngine.System); 

    private AIService aiService;
    final AIDataService aiDataService = new AIDataService(config);
    final AIRequest aiRequest = new AIRequest();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]  {Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO},1);//permission from manifest file


        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
        addBtn = findViewById(R.id.addBtn);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new  LinearLayoutManager(this);
        linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

         Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("chats").limitToLast(50);//upto 50 characters to be displayed

        ref.keepSynced(true);//i don't know its purpose. Please explain :')

        aiService = AIService.getService(this, config);
        aiService.setListener(this);

        addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                String message = editText.getText().toString().trim();

                if (!message.equals("")) {

                    ChatMessage chatMessage = new ChatMessage(message, "user");
                    ref.child("chat").push().setValue(chatMessage);


                    aiRequest.setQuery(message);
  //MyAsyncTask is a subclass of MainActivity extending ASyncTask
                    MyAsyncTask myasynctask = new MyAsyncTask();
                    myasynctask.execute();    
                    }
                else {
                    aiService.startListening();
                }

                editText.setText("");

            }
        });

//Below code changes the image ie when audio is recorded it is mic else //arrow for sending message

        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                ImageView fab_img = findViewById(R.id.fab_img);
                Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ic_send_white_24dp);
                Bitmap img1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ic_mic_white_24dp);


                if (s.toString().trim().length()!=0 && flagFab){
                    ImageViewAnimatedChange(MainActivity.this,fab_img,img);

                    flagFab=false;

                }
                else if (s.toString().trim().length()==0){
                    ImageViewAnimatedChange(MainActivity.this,fab_img,img1);
                    flagFab=true;

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });

//FirebaseRecyclerOption below because firebase+recycler view

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<ChatMessage>options=new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<ChatMessage>().setQuery(query,ChatMessage.class).build();
        //Chatmessage,chat_rec//<image_details,blogviewholder>=<same>()<image_details.class,r.lao

        final FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ChatMessage, chat_rec> adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ChatMessage, chat_rec>(options) {

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public chat_rec onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.msglist,parent,false);//R.layout.msglist is the default layout for chats

                return new chat_rec(view);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(chat_rec holder, int position, ChatMessage model) {
                // Bind the Chat object to the ChatHolder
                // ...

                if (model.getMsgUser().equals("user")) {


                    holder.rightText.setText(model.getMsgText());

                    holder.rightText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.leftText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                else {
                    holder.leftText.setText(model.getMsgText());

                    holder.rightText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.leftText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

            }

        };

        adapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
        @Override
        public void onItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
                super.onItemRangeInserted(positionStart, itemCount);

                int msgCount = adapter.getItemCount();
                int lastVisiblePosition = linearLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();

                if (lastVisiblePosition == -1 ||
                        (positionStart >= (msgCount - 1) &&
                                lastVisiblePosition == (positionStart - 1))) {
                    recyclerView.scrollToPosition(positionStart);

                }

            }
        });
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }//onCreate ends here


//Ayncronous Task defined here:

        private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<AIRequest,Void,AIResponse>{


        @Override
        protected AIResponse doInBackground(AIRequest... aiRequests) {
            final AIRequest request = aiRequests[0];
            try {
                final AIResponse response =         aiDataService.request(aiRequest);
                return response;
            } catch (AIServiceException e) {
            }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(AIResponse response) {
            //super.onPostExecute(response);

            if (response != null) {

                Result result = response.getResult();
                String reply = result.getFulfillment().getSpeech();
                ChatMessage chatMessage = new ChatMessage(reply, "KG Precision Moulders");
                ref.child("Tech Support").push().setValue(chatMessage);
            }
        }
    }

/*While recording audio there should be mic image in button and when typing message there should be arrow*/
    public void ImageViewAnimatedChange(Context c, final ImageView v, final Bitmap new_image) {
        final Animation anim_out = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(c, R.anim.zoom_out);
        final Animation anim_in  = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(c, R.anim.zoom_in);
        anim_out.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener()
        {
            @Override public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}
            @Override public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
            @Override public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)
            {
                v.setImageBitmap(new_image);
                anim_in.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                    @Override public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}
                    @Override public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
                    @Override public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {}
                });
                v.startAnimation(anim_in);
            }
        });
        v.startAnimation(anim_out);
    }
        @Override
        public void onResult(ai.api.model.AIResponse response) {
            Result result = response.getResult();
            String message = result.getResolvedQuery();
            ChatMessage chatMessage0 = new ChatMessage(message, "user");
            ref.child("chat").push().setValue(chatMessage0);
            String reply = result.getFulfillment().getSpeech();
            ChatMessage chatMessage = new ChatMessage(reply, "bot");
            ref.child("chat").push().setValue(chatMessage);
    }
```

There are zero errors in the code but the logcat when I select firebase shows these errors:

```
E/SystemUpdate-Connection: create session error : RESULT_ERROR

E/MiPicks-Connection: create session error : RESULT_ERROR

E/MiPicks-ConnectionRSA: get key exception : com.android.org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.DecoderException: unable to decode base64 string: invalid characters encountered in base64 data
```

And I am getting a RecyclerViewException too. Probably errors are due to the fact that the RecyclerView isnt getting inflated:

```
Process: com.example.internchatbot, PID: 6443
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.internchatbot/com.example.internchatbot.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2747)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2808)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1541)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:165)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6375)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:802)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.internchatbot-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.internchatbot-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.internchatbot-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.internchatbot-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.internchatbot-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.internchatbot-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.internchatbot-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.internchatbot-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.internchatbot-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.internchatbot-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.internchatbot-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.internchatbot-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.internchatbot-1/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:74)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:812)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:752)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:883)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:846)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:522)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:430)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at com.example.internchatbot.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:68)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6845)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2700)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2808)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1541)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:165)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6375)
2019-07-02 00:47:44.291 6443-6443/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:802)
```

I could do till here. Help me guys! I am dead tired!

Comment: can you post the value which you are trying to decode.

Comment: Value as in, I couldn't understand..

Answer (score 0):

> Firebase app registration to connect to its server was taking a lot of time, so I skipped the step thinking I would connect it through my google-json file.

It's important to register your app to Firebase console, and then make sure you have google-services.json file in your project. It contains API Key, and some configuration things. Not having it may lead to errors such as what you're dealing with now.

Comment: Sir I'm trying to register it but it isn't geting registered (ie the Firebase console keeps on checking to register the app) probably because since my recycler view isn't getting inflated so Firebase connection part isn't getting implemented.

Comment: In the logcat, the warning for java.lang.Runtime Exception is before FireBase error hence the above statement.

Comment: Can you show us your `layout/activity_main.xml` file? Maybe there's some mis-configuration in the file.

Comment: There was a misconfiguration in one line in my layout/activity_main.xml which I resolved ie since I migrated from android to androidx my recycler view in xml file needed this initialization < androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView..../> instead of the older android version one.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your firebase error occurs due to recycler view. It means app crashed before firebase can start its session.

So I suggest you to first fix recyclerview inflation error. For that please check if below library exists in your app level `build.gradle` file.

```
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
```

Comment: Yes sir it exists in my app.gradle as you can see from above -  implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0-rc02'

Answer (score 0):

Here in this case since I migrated from android to androidx, I had to change my layout/activity_main.xml definition of the previous RecyclerView ie from 
`android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView` to `androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView` as Mr. Yosi pointed out to me.

Hence, my updated activity_main.xml file:

```
    <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.internchatbot.MainActivity"
     >
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView  <!--change made here-->
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="50dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:background="#f4f6f7"
        />
     ...
     ...
</RelativeLayout>
```